# Reason behind these MariaDB deadlocks

Tags: mariadb, deadlock, galera

My application is getting a lot of MariaDB deadlocks for, in my opinion, no reason. I know deadlocks happen if two or more transactions are both waiting for the other transaction to finish, but in my case there is no reason for the transaction to not run after each other.

I'm using a Galera Cluster with 3 MariaDB nodes; version 10.5.12.

These are 2 transactions that get in a deadlock with each other, could someone explain why?

Transaction 1:

```
UPDATE `trt_employees` SET `availability`=
  CASE 
    WHEN `availability`='99' THEN `availability`+'1' 
    ELSE `availability`+'2'
  END
WHERE `company` IN ('241','94','208') AND `availability`<'100'
```

Transaction 2:

```
UPDATE `trt_employees` SET `lastorder`='91' WHERE `id` = '284190'
```

Full log:

```
srv_master_thread loops: 101853 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 53165 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 155014
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 4741
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 12078
RW-shared spins 1215, rounds 10186, OS waits 93
RW-excl spins 1086, rounds 8271, OS waits 201
RW-sx spins 69, rounds 479, OS waits 7
Spin rounds per wait: 8.38 RW-shared, 7.62 RW-excl, 6.94 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2021-11-10 06:40:08 0x7f9f8c760700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 763334644, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 309 lock struct(s), heap size 41080, 12835 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 774400, OS thread handle 140322157614848, query id 12767202 crons Updating
UPDATE `trt_employees` 
                                SET `availability`=
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN `availability`='99' THEN `availability`+'1' 
                                        ELSE `availability`+'2'
                                    END
                                WHERE `company` IN ('241','94','208') AND `availability`<'100'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1186 page no 30 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `TRT`.`trt_employees` trx id 763334644 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 11 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 22; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80045e10; asc   ^ ;
 1: len 6; hex 00002d7f8ff5; asc   -   ;
 2: len 7; hex 04000001842e27; asc      .;
 3: len 2; hex 800c; asc   ;
 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;
 5: len 4; hex 8000dcbf; asc     ;
 6: SQL NULL;
 7: len 2; hex 805b; asc  [;
 8: len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;
 9: len 2; hex 805d; asc  ];
 10: len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;
 11: len 1; hex 89; asc  ;
 12: len 2; hex 8032; asc  2;
 13: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;
 14: len 5; hex 99ab14654a; asc    eJ;
 15: len 3; hex 8000d4; asc    ;
 16: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 17: len 5; hex 99a5421a73; asc   B s;
 18: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 19: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 21: len 2; hex 8001; asc   ;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 763334645, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 774399, OS thread handle 140323233072896, query id 12767214 secuser Updating
UPDATE `trt_employees` SET `lastorder`='91' WHERE `id` = '284190'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1186 page no 30 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `TRT`.`trt_employees` trx id 763334645 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 11 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 22; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80045e10; asc   ^ ;
 1: len 6; hex 00002d7f8ff5; asc   -   ;
 2: len 7; hex 04000001842e27; asc      .;
 3: len 2; hex 800c; asc   ;
 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;
 5: len 4; hex 8000dcbf; asc     ;
 6: SQL NULL;
 7: len 2; hex 805b; asc  [;
 8: len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;
 9: len 2; hex 805d; asc  ];
 10: len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;
 11: len 1; hex 89; asc  ;
 12: len 2; hex 8032; asc  2;
 13: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;
 14: len 5; hex 99ab14654a; asc    eJ;
 15: len 3; hex 8000d4; asc    ;
 16: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 17: len 5; hex 99a5421a73; asc   B s;
 18: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 19: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 21: len 2; hex 8001; asc   ;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1186 page no 29 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `TRT`.`trt_employees` trx id 763334645 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 197 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 22; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8004561e; asc   V ;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000000; asc       ;
 2: len 7; hex 80000000000000; asc        ;
 3: len 2; hex 800d; asc   ;
 4: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;
 5: len 4; hex 8000dcbf; asc     ;
 6: SQL NULL;
 7: len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;
 8: len 2; hex 805b; asc  [;
 9: len 2; hex 8064; asc  d;
 10: len 2; hex 8006; asc   ;
 11: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 12: len 2; hex 8005; asc   ;
 13: len 4; hex 80d8c8fc; asc     ;
 14: len 5; hex 99ab14654a; asc    eJ;
 15: len 3; hex 8000d4; asc    ;
 16: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 17: len 5; hex 99a4faf889; asc      ;
 18: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 19: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;
 21: len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 763471790
Purge done for trxs n:o < 763471789 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421798219723120, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421798219718864, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
10184 OS file reads, 853244 OS file writes, 112814 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 5.66 writes/s, 0.67 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 543, seg size 545, 368 merges
merged operations:
 insert 2189, delete mark 31912, delete 434
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
0.00 hash searches/s, 13270.91 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 319011717382
Log flushed up to   319011717183
Pages flushed up to 319002391226
Last checkpoint at  319002381933
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
826209 log i/os done, 5.67 log i/os/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 301989888
Dictionary memory allocated 2069400
Buffer pool size   16130
Free buffers       5197
Database pages     10933
Old database pages 4015
Modified db pages  1474
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 9.138
Max dirty pages percent: 90.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0
Pages made young 420763, not young 689721
3.33 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 10014, created 4716, written 26838
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 10933, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=0, Main thread ID=0, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 398804, updated 1523396, deleted 380092, read 11554972891
0.67 inserts/s, 7.33 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 210748.75 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 10, updated 0, deleted 11, read 27
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
```

Comment: whats the result of select * from  `trt_employees`  WHERE `id` = '284190'

Comment: @AliFidanli That returns 1 row from that table with `availability` at 100, `lastorder` at 161, `company` at 94. So both transactions will update that same row, but that's still not a reason for a deadlock right?

Comment: According to the error log, the second transaction already holds a lock on id 286224 (and that is actually the id that transaction 1 wants to update, but can't). Do you have other (uncommitted) queries in your 2nd transaction before this update?

Comment: There is 1 query in front of this one in the 2nd transaction, this one will update fields for another employee: `UPDATE trt_employees SET availability=availability-'1', lastorder='245' WHERE id='293361'`

Comment: I can only tell you what the log is telling me, and it says that you have a lock on id 286224, and that lock is (correctly) causing the deadlock (as a check if that makes sense you could verify if that id has a company IN ('241','94','208')) . It's possible that it is an indirect effect, e.g. via a foreign key or trigger. Also selects can lock. Can you check again and/or add the complete transaction, maybe it gives us another idea.

Comment: Does that table have `INDEX(company)`?

Comment: Consider this instead of the `SET .. CASE ..`:  `SET availability = LEAST(availability + 2, 100)`

Comment: @Solarflare Where do you see id 286224 in the logs? Because I don't see it.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, it has. Thanks for the info, learned something new with that, great! :)

Comment: Under "HOLDS THE LOCK(S):", the first entry, "0: len 4; hex 80045e10; asc   ^ ;" is integer 286224. And transaction 1 waits for that same id. So transaction 2 locked that id, transaction 1 wants to update that id, and transaction 2 wants to update id 284190 that transaction 1 has a lock on, so the deadlock is valid. The question seem to be why that id got locked, and if you don't know, please add the complete transaction 2 (from "start transaction"), so we may make a guess where it happened. Also include all foreign keys and triggers of all tables used in that transaction.